# Image runs out of page

Tags: tables, graphics

I have an issue with displaying an image in `tabular`.
This is the code I actually use:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{10.5cm}ll}     Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand &  \multirow{3}{4pt}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png}}   
\end{tabular}
```

In some cases, the image is at the very end of a page, so the image is not fully displayed, it also does not break the page to a new one. It looks like this (at the black line the new page begins):

[image]

Is there a possibility to force a page break, in that case that the image is not completely on the page?
Many thanks in advance for any hint!

Here is the full example TeX code (you need to replace the `graphicspath` value and you need to have an image here: `images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\geometry{    left=2.5cm,    right=1.5cm,    top=2cm,    bottom=2.5cm,    bindingoffset=0.5mm  }  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\usepackage{tabu}  
\usepackage{lastpage}  
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[space]{grffile}  
\usepackage{marginnote}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}  
\graphicspath{ {D:/Private/some-domain.de/public/} }  
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}    
\definecolor{reportGrey}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}     
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}    
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}    
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}    
\headheight = 39pt   
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhf{}   
\rhead{ \textcolor{reportGrey}{22.04.21\\Seite \thepage\hspace{1pt}/\pageref{LastPage}}}   
\lhead{ \textcolor{reportGrey}{ {\Large{Meine Einzelunternehmung}} \linebreak Straße 1a \linebreak 012345 Stadt} }      
\lfoot{\vspace{-16,8cm}  \hspace{-1cm}   \rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{reportGrey}{Bemessungsmodul: T12 - Druckstab \textbar Version 1.0.0:607 | www.some-domain.de}}   
\\\vspace{.24cm}}       
\begin{document}    
\section*{brandschutztechnische Bemessung}  Bemessungsverfahren nach DIN 1995-1-2:2010-12 nach der Methode mit reduziertem Querschnitt    
\subsection*{Schnittgrößen}  Schnittgrößen am Auflager A (\(x\) = \(L\) = 3.00 m)  
\begin{equation*}       
N_{d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} - 1.00 * G_k = -37.45 - 1.00 * 0.45 = -37.90  \text{ kN}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
V_{z,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} * e_z}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 * 60}{3.00} * 10^{-3} = -0.56 \text{ kN}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
V_{y,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} * e_y}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 * 50}{3.00} * 10^{-3} = -0.62 \text{ kN}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}  
M_{y,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} * e_z = -37.45 * 60 * 10^{-3} = -1.67 \text{ kNm}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
M_{z,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} * e_y = -37.45 * 50 * 10^{-3} = -1.87 \text{ kNm}  
\end{equation*}    
\subsection*{Festigkeits- und Steifigkeitswerte}  
\begin{tabular}{p{1.6cm}p{3.5cm}p{1.9cm}p{5.5cm}ll}  
\(k_{mod,fi}\) : &  1.00 & \(k_{fi}\)  : & 1.25 & \(\gamma_{M,fi}\) : & 1.00i\\  
\end{tabular}  
\begin{equation*}  
f_{c,0,d,fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{f_{c,0,k}}{\gamma_{M,fi}} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{21.00}{1.00} = 26.25 \text{ N/mm$^2$}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}  
\begin{split}  
k_{h,y} &= min  
\begin{cases}  
\left( \dfrac{150}{b} \right)^{0.2} = \left( \dfrac{150}{140} \right)^{0.2} = 1.01 \\  1.3  
\end{cases}  
\end{split}  
\end{equation*}        
\begin{equation*}       
f_{m,y,d_fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{f_{m,k}}{\gamma_M,fi} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{24.00}{1.00} = 30.00 \text{ N/mm$^2$}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
f_{m,z,d,fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{k_{h,y} * f_{m,k}}{\gamma_M,fi} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{1.01 * 24.00}{1.00} = 30.30 \text{ N/mm$^2$}  
\end{equation*}    
\subsection*{Querschnittswerte}  
\begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{2.5cm}p{1.9cm}p{4.0cm}ll}  
Abbrandrate \(\beta_n\): &  0.80 mm/min & \(d_{0}\)  : & 7.00 mm & Branddauer \(t\) : & 30.00 min\\  
\end{tabular}  
\begin{equation*}  
d_{char,n} = \beta_n * t = 0.80 * 30.00  = 24.00 \text{ mm}  \tag{\text{DIN EN 1995-1-2:2010-12, Gl. 3.2}}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
d_{ef} = d_{char,n} + k_0 * d_0 = 24.00 + 1.00 * 7.00  = 31.00 \text{ mm}  \tag{\text{DIN EN 1995-1-2:2010-12, Gl. 4.1}}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{tabular}{p{10.5cm}ll}     
Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand &  \multirow{3}{4pt}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png}}   
\end{tabular}  
\begin{equation*}       
b_t = b - 2 * d_{ef} = 140 - 2 * 31 = 78 \text{ mm}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
h_t = h - 2 * d_{ef} = 180 - 2 * 31 = 118 \text{ mm}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
A_r = b_t * h_t = 78 * 118 * 10^{-2} = 92.04 \text{ cm$^2$}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
W_{y,r} = \dfrac{b_t*h_t^2}{6} = \dfrac{78*118^2}{6} * 10^{-3} = 181.01 \text{ cm$^3$}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
W_{z,r} = \dfrac{h_t*b_t^2}{6} = \dfrac{118*78^2}{6} * 10^{-3} = 119.65 \text{ cm$^3$}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
i_{y,r} = \dfrac{h_t}{\sqrt{12}} = \dfrac{118}{\sqrt{12}} = 34.06 \text{ mm}  
\end{equation*}  
\begin{equation*}       
i_{z,r} = \dfrac{b_t}{\sqrt{12}} = \dfrac{78}{\sqrt{12}} = 22.52 \text{ mm}  
\end{equation*}    
\subsubsection{verwendete Normen}  
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}ll}  
DIN EN 338:2016-07 & Bauholz für tragende Zwecke   \\  
DIN EN 1995-1-1:2010-12 & Eurocode 5: Bemessung und Konstruktion von Holzbauteilen, Teil 1-1 \\  
DIN EN 1995-1-1/A2:2014-07 & Änderung  A2 zu EC5 \\    
DIN EN 1995-1-1/NA:2013-08 & Nationaler Anhang (EC5) \\   \\  
\end{tabular}        
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**
The solution of @Zarko works. The image is displayed on the next page, if it does not fit on the page.
But it is no optimal solution, because with this big "gaps" occur on the left side (see the image below):

[image]

Is there a way to avoid these "gaps" and display all the texts and formulas directly below each other with having the image on the right side?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Probably a table isn't the best way to present this kind of information. Depending on the specific requirements, minipages or an approach based on two columns could also work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question with the full TeX code example.

Comment: Try to insert `\pagebreak` before table with image.

Comment: @Zarko That does not solve my issue. I don't want to enter at a page break all the time. Only if it comes to the situation described above!

Comment: As far I see, result is exactly how you ask in question. Be aware, that you in question (exactly in provided MWE) require that image is in line with text "Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand". So, the text before and after this text should not intrude in image. With your complain about result your question is not clear anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
\begin{tabular}{p{10.5cm}ll}     
Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand &  \multirow{3}{4pt}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png}}   
\end{tabular}
```

write

```
Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand\hfill  
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth, valign=c]{example-image-duck} %{images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png}}
```

and in document preamble replace `usepackage{graphicx}` with `usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`.

Note:

- I would remove `*` symbols for multiplications and instead them use `\cdot` where is necessary
- For units I would use `siunitx` package
- series of `equations*` I would write as `gather*`, for example the first in your document example as:

```
\begin{gather*}
N_{d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} - 1.00 G_k = -37.45 - 1.00 0.45 = \SI{-37.90}{kN} 
\\
V_{z,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} e_z}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 60}{3.00} 10^{-3} = \SI{-0.56}{kN}
\\
V_{y,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} e_y}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 50}{3.00} 10^{-3} = \SI{-0.62}{kN}
\\
M_{y,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} e_z = -37.45\cdot 60\cdot10^{-3} = \SI{-1.67}{kNm}
\\
M_{z,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} e_y = -37.45\cdot50\cdot10^{-3} = -1.87 \text{kNm}
\end{gather*}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red line indicate text left border)

**Addendum:**
After last comment/complains seems that you look for something like this:

[image]

For above result you need in preamble to load `wrapfig` package. A MWE, which produce (on the seconad page) above image is:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm},    
          vmargin={2.5cm},    
          bindingoffset=0.5mm,
          headheight = 39pt
          }
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % <---
%\graphicspath{ {D:/Private/some-domain.de/public/} }
\usepackage{siunitx}            % <---
\usepackage{wrapfig}            % <---

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{reportGrey}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{ \textcolor{reportGrey}{22.04.21\\Seite \thepage\hspace{1pt}/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\lhead{ \textcolor{reportGrey}{ {\Large{Meine Einzelunternehmung}} \linebreak Straße 1a \linebreak 012345 Stadt} }
\lfoot{\vspace{-16,8cm}  \hspace{-1cm}   \rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{reportGrey}{Bemessungsmodul: T12 - Druckstab \textbar Version 1.0.0:607 | www.some-domain.de}}
\\\vspace{.24cm}}

\begin{document}
\section*{brandschutztechnische Bemessung}  
Bemessungsverfahren nach DIN 1995-1-2:2010-12 nach der Methode mit reduziertem Querschnitt

\subsection*{Schnittgrößen}  
Schnittgrößen am Auflager A (\(x\) = \(L\) = 3.00 m)
\begin{gather*}
N_{d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} - 1.00 G_k = -37.45 - 1.00 0.45 = \SI{-37.90}{kN}
\\
V_{z,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} e_z}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 60}{3.00} 10^{-3} = \SI{-0.56}{kN}
\\
V_{y,d,fi} = \dfrac{-F_{c,d,fi} e_y}{L} = \dfrac{-37.45 50}{3.00} 10^{-3} = \SI{-0.62}{kN}
\\
M_{y,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} e_z = -37.45\cdot 60\cdot10^{-3} = \SI{-1.67}{kNm}
\\
M_{z,d,fi} = -F_{c,d,fi} e_y = -37.45\cdot50\cdot10^{-3} = -1.87 \text{kNm}
\end{gather*}

\subsection*{Festigkeits- und Steifigkeitswerte}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.6cm}p{3.5cm}p{1.9cm}p{5.5cm}ll}
\(k_{mod,fi}\) : &  1.00 & \(k_{fi}\)  : & 1.25 & \(\gamma_{M,fi}\) : & 1.00i\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{gather*}
f_{c,0,d,fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{f_{c,0,k}}{\gamma_{M,fi}} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{21.00}{1.00} = 26.25 \text{ N/mm$^2$}
\\
\begin{split}
k_{h,y} = \min\begin{cases}
    \left( \dfrac{150}{b} \right)^{0.2} = \left( \dfrac{150}{140} \right)^{0.2} = 1.01 \\  
    1.3
    \end{cases}
\end{split}
\\
f_{m,y,d_fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{f_{m,k}}{\gamma_M,fi} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{24.00}{1.00} = 30.00 \text{ N/mm$^2$}
\\
f_{m,z,d,fi} = k_{mod,fi} * k_{fi} * \dfrac{k_{h,y} * f_{m,k}}{\gamma_M,fi} = 1.00 * 1.25 * \dfrac{1.01 * 24.00}{1.00} = 30.30 \text{ N/mm$^2$}
\end{gather*}

\subsection*{Querschnittswerte}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{2.5cm}p{1.9cm}p{4.0cm}ll}
Abbrandrate \(\beta_n\): &  0.80 mm/min & \(d_{0}\)  : & 7.00 mm & Branddauer \(t\) : & 30.00 min\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{equation*}
d_{char,n} = \beta_n * t = 0.80 * 30.00  = 24.00 \text{ mm}  \tag{\text{DIN EN 1995-1-2:2010-12, Gl. 3.2}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
d_{ef} = d_{char,n} + k_0 * d_0 = 24.00 + 1.00 * 7.00  = 31.00 \text{ mm}  \tag{\text{DIN EN 1995-1-2:2010-12, Gl. 4.1}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{0.32\linewidth} % <----
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} %{images/Druckstab/Brandschutz/Brand_rechteck-oxlr.png}}
\end{wrapfigure}
Brandschutz: R30, 3-seitiger Abbrand   
\begin{gather*}
b_t = b - 2 * d_{ef} = 140 - 2 * 31 = 78 \text{ mm}
\\
h_t = h - 2 * d_{ef} = 180 - 2 * 31 = 118 \text{ mm}
\\
A_r = b_t * h_t = 78 * 118 * 10^{-2} = 92.04 \text{ cm$^2$}
\\
W_{y,r} = \dfrac{b_t*h_t^2}{6} = \dfrac{78*118^2}{6} * 10^{-3} = 181.01 \text{ cm$^3$}
\\
W_{z,r} = \dfrac{h_t*b_t^2}{6} = \dfrac{118*78^2}{6} * 10^{-3} = 119.65 \text{ cm$^3$}
\\
i_{y,r} = \dfrac{h_t}{\sqrt{12}} = \dfrac{118}{\sqrt{12}} = 34.06 \text{ mm}
\\
i_{z,r} = \dfrac{b_t}{\sqrt{12}} = \dfrac{78}{\sqrt{12}} = 22.52 \text{ mm}
\end{gather*}

\subsubsection{Verwendete Normen}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}ll}
DIN EN 338:2016-07 & Bauholz für tragende Zwecke   \\
DIN EN 1995-1-1:2010-12 & Eurocode 5: Bemessung und Konstruktion von Holzbauteilen, Teil 1-1 \\
DIN EN 1995-1-1/A2:2014-07 & Änderung  A2 zu EC5 \\
DIN EN 1995-1-1/NA:2013-08 & Nationaler Anhang (EC5) \\   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for providing your answer. Your solution does not fullfil 100% my issue. Please read the update part of my question. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you see the issue with your solution? Do you have an idea to this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I see. It is exactly why you require in your question. Apparently you was not clear, what you like to have. Now I guessing, that you looking for wrapped figure right of equations ... See addendum to answer (will appear soon).

Comment: Yes, many thanks for your help. That's exactly what I'm looking for!